# Regular expression to find and replace wrong quotation marks

Tags: regex, latex, sublimetext2

I have a document which has been copy/pasted from MS Word. All the quotations are copied as `''something''` which basically is creating a mess in my LaTeX document, hence they have to be ``` ``something'' ```.

Is it possible to make a regular expression that finds all these `''something''` where `something` can be anything (including symbols, numbers etc.), and a regular expression that replaces it with the correct quotation? I am using Sublime Text which is able to use RegEX directly in the editor.

Comment: did you wan to replace the first `''` with two backticks?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that is basically my goal, yes. So first find `''something''` and then replacing the first two `''` with ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below regex would match all the double single quoted strings and capture  all the characters except the first two single quotes(only in the matched string). Replacing the matched characters with double backticks plus the characters inside group index 1 will give you the desired result.

Regex:

```
''(.*?'')
```

Replacemnet string:

```
``$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/64)